# PHPExcel mergeCells() causing unreadable content

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've been working with PHPExcel over the last few days and so far it's been perfect for what I need. However, today I've been trying to use mergeCells for "colspan" functionality but when I do it causes unreadable content errors and MS Excel prompts me to repair the file.

The code I'm using is:

```
$first = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($xCount).$yCount;    
$second = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex( $xCount + 2).$yCount;
$cell_merge = $first.":".$second;   
$this->excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells( $cell_merge );
```

I've output the result of `$first, $second` and `$cell_merge` to ensure I'm going about it the right way and the content is correct. Furthermore, when I try a static merge of cells (by entering `mergeCells('A1:C1');` it works perfectly.

Would it be possible that trying to write to a merged cell would cause problems?

EDIT: just a note: I also tried to cast the variable as string just in case like this:

```
$this->excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells( (string)$cell_merge );
```

... but no luck.

Comment: As always when you get "unreadable content errors" when trying to open a PHPExcel-generated file in MS Excel, try opening the file in a text editor and looking for any PHP or PHPExcel error messages at the top of the file

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) When I did, it's all just jumbled characters . I can't pick an error out of the file. Where should I be looking?

Comment: If there ws an error, it would typically be at the very beginning or the very end of the file, and clearly obvious as plain text

Comment: Oh, in that case then no; there is no plain text in the file except for a few file paths like: `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference. The problem here existed between the keyboard and chair.

I was attempting to change the colspan during a loop and in this loop I had a call to mergeCells with 'A0:C0'.

When passing row "0" I wasn't getting any errors, just a bad excel sheet. Something to bear in mind.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know... it means I don't need to spend any more time looking for a bug in the merge method